# Rendering Rails partial view (with issues reading the Rails API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actioncontroller

I have a jQuery post submitting a form to a controller `create` action, which works great. If the `save` was successful I would like the `create` action to return a different form so the `success` callback will insert this form. Is this possible?

Here's my code:

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

      if @event.save
        # This is where I would like to render a different controller action's view.
        render :controller => "shows", :action => "new", :layout => false
      else
        render action: "new"
      end
  end
```

For some reason it will not render the "shows/new" template. It keeps rendering the current controller's `new` template without the layout. What am I missing here?

As an aside, I had a look at api.rubyonrails.org and tried to look up the `render` method. I found it listed as `render(context,options)`, but can't for the life of me find out what the valid options are. This seems to be a common pattern for a lot of methods. How do I find out? It will certainly help me figure out what my options are, and perhaps give various things a try.

Thanks,
Dany.

ADDED: I have now used `render "shows/new", :layout => false` in my controller action, which is working. In my new.html.erb for Shows I have declared `<%= render "/shows/form" %>`. Unfortunately I am now getting 500 error. I found this in development.log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
    1: <%= form_for(@show) do |f| %>
    2:   <% if @show.errors.any? %>
    3:     <div id="error_explanation">
    4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@show.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this show from being saved:</h2>
  app/views/shows/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shows__form_html_erb___1397093944823648986_2158339140'
  app/views/shows/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shows_new_html_erb__1152608637968596369_2158584080'
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:61:in `create'
```

I'm not entirely sure what's causing this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you missed: `2.2.3 Rendering an Action’s Template from Another Controller`

Try:

```
 render "shows/new", :layout => false
```

Comment: Wonder how I missed that. Thanks - half way there! Now I have a weirdness where it renders the correct template, but not the correct "_form" within that template. It's not rendering "shows/_form" within "shows/new"

Comment: ok it's because the controller is still the bad one, you should provide absolute path in the render of your partial

Comment: Are you referring to `2.2.4 Rendering an Arbitrary File`?

Comment: no I'm talking about partials in views so `3.4.1 Naming Partials`

Comment: Ok, in `shows > new.html.erb` I now have `<%= render 'shows/form' %>`. Now I get 500 error.

Comment: That's getting better, it's targeting the right _form now. I'm still stuck though - I have edited the question to include the error. Thanks for all your help so far, I'm getting really close.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4650/discussion-between-apneadiving-and-danyw)